# A ton of "CS0246: type or namespace not found" after opening a project on 2021.3.6f1

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine

Every time whenever I open a project with Unity 2021.x a project gets a ton of errors for seemingly no reason.
[220 CS0246:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZpAG.png)

I even reinstalled window 10 and downloaded windows 11. Errors are consistent. Projects opened with 2020 and 2022 don't have such issues.
I suspected that the problem is with .net but switching Api compatibility level doesn't do a thing.
[This is how it looks in scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDrnB.png)

I could probably add the references manually, but that's third party packages so I would rather not change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try out:

**Solution 1:**

You can try and delete the `using DG.Tweening;` and then try right click on your `Ease` reference and probably it will suggest you for Visual Studio to import any missing files or namespaces.

[image]

**Solution 2:**

Create a reference like this and see if the error is still there.

```
[SerializeField] protected DG.Tweening.Ease _ease = DG.Tweening.Ease.Linear;
```

**Solution 3:**

Try re-install your [DOTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676) package from Unity's assets store.

Comment: I reinstalled the packages and it helped. The modules needed some stuff that was ignored in git.